How to pass MDC data from main thread to webserver http threads
I'm using Spring Boot and MDC to log additional context with each log entry in my REST API application. I use MDC in the main thread, but the data is not passed to the http threads that are created through the REST controllers (spawned by the webserver).
Here's a simplified example of my current logging output:
> thread: main, data1: foo, data2: bar, data3: null, message: some log entry
> thread: main, data1: foo, data2: bar, data3: null, message: some other log entry
> thread: http-nio-1234-1, data1: null, data2: null, data3: foobar, message: some other log entry
> thread: http-nio-1234-2, data1: null, data2: null, data3: foobar, message: some other log entry

As you can see, data1 and data2 (set in the main thread) are only available in the main thread logs, while data3 (set in a http thread) is available in all other http threads spawned by the webserver.
How can I pass the MDC data from the main thread to these webserver http threads?
I've found plenty of documentation on passing MDC data to async threads, but that doesn't apply to my scenario.
I'm using Spring Boot and logging framework SLF4J. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Threads are always async, even when you are waiting for the result.

@M.Deinum hmm okay, I tried with the code for passing it to async threads but it doesn't work. And I got the info they are not async. Let me add that code as well.

How are your "sub-threads" created?

@forty-two I am unclear, that seems to be some spring "magic". I am obviously not very confident in spring. Same as for Java too to be honest.

The rest controller has a @RestController annotation. It seems that is what will spawn a new thread for each request made under the hood.

The main thread has nothing to do with the http threads (those are from tomcat). So you cannot copy from the main to the the http threads.

You need to create you own handler implementing HandlerInterceptor and set MDC context in preHandle.
There is no universal way to make all threads to use your MDC context unless you wan to be involved in dark magic of runtime code manipulation.

I see but almost all threads already share the MDC, except the main thread. Here I set some initial values that are very important for debugging in the http threads to understand which values they are running with.
I thought because the main is spawing these thread it should be possible to send the data to them whilst spawning them.

@steros "almost all threads already share the MDC" you got lucky. There are plenty of libraries and framework that don't use thread pool provided by Spring. If you use one of them you'll have to handle it individually.
